# How to delete a particular folder from github account

Tags: github

I wish to delete a particular folder from my github repository.

Here is the image -

[image]

```
 git init

 git remote add origin '...'

 git rm -r --cached 'folder_name'


 error - fatal: pathspec 'COMGO/Bkp' did not match any files
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Web Interface**

You can delete a file using delete button but you cannot directly delete a folder via the web-interface. The way to delete a folder from GitHub.com is to delete every file inside it.

**Terminal**

Steps to remove directory

```
git rm -r --cached FolderName
git commit -m "Removed folder from repository"
git push origin master
```